# Flutter oauth2 login with discord. redirect doesn't work

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm looking to make a button login with discord. For that I use flutter_web_auth but discord shows me an error with the redirect URI and appear black screenshot on device

```
<activity android:name="com.linusu.flutter_web_auth.CallbackActivity" >
       <intent-filter android:label="flutter_web_auth">
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
           <data android:scheme="http" android:host="com.example.hola" />
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>
void loginWithDiscord() async {
```

// App specific variables

```
const clientId = 'myClientId' ;
const callbackUrlScheme = 'com.area';
const redirectUri = 'com.area://home'; // OR 'com.area:/';
```

// Construct the url

```
final url = Uri.https('discord.com', '/api/oauth2/authorize', {
  'response_type': 'code',
  'client_id': clientId,
  'redirect_uri': redirectUri,
  'scope': 'identify',
});
```

// Present the dialog to the user

```
final result = await FlutterWebAuth.authenticate(
    url: url.toString(), callbackUrlScheme: callbackUrlScheme);
```

// Extract code from resulting url

```
final code = Uri.parse(result).queryParameters['code'];
```

// Use this code to get an access token

```
final response = await http
    .post(Uri.parse('https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize'), body: {
  'client_id': clientId,
  'redirect_uri': redirectUri,
  'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
  'code': code,
});
```

// Get the access token from the response

```
final accessToken = jsonDecode(response.body)['access_token'] as String;
print(accessToken);
```

}

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> redirect_uri is whatever URL you registered when creating your application, url-encoded

See [Authorization Code Grant](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#authorization-code-grant) for details

Comment: no works,appear authorization screen for 1 second or less and then balc screen and console no error code!